# Put plotly legend on top of chart

Tags: r, plotly

How can I put the legend on top of the plotly chart instead of bottom?

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)

data <- spread(Orange, Tree, circumference)
data <- rename(data, c("1" = "Tree1", "2" = "Tree2", "3" = "Tree3", "4" = "Tree4", "5" = "Tree5"))

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~age, y = ~Tree1, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = 'Tree 1')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Tree2, name = 'Tree 2')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Tree3, name = 'Tree 3')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Tree4, name = 'Tree 4')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Tree5, name = 'Tree 5')
fig <- fig %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h'))

fig
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify the x and y coordinates of the `legend` in `layout` like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~age, y = ~Tree1, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = 'Tree 1')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Tree2, name = 'Tree 2')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Tree3, name = 'Tree 3')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Tree4, name = 'Tree 4')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~Tree5, name = 'Tree 5')
fig <- fig %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h', x = 0, y = 1.1))

fig
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>